# Snorkeling in South-East Ishigaki (between airport and city)

Tags: japan, beaches, diving, okinawa, ishigaki

In [Ishigaki](https://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Ishigaki), I am planning to walk or cycle from the [airport](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_Ishigaki_Airport) to the city center, along the South-East coast.

**QUESTION:** Are there snorkeling spots on the way?

- Close enough to the beach to reach without a boat
- Not more dangerous than the average snorkeling spot (winds, currents, etc)
- Fish and reef (the more the better)

By snorkeling I mean staying at the surface and looking into the water with a mask, with a snorkel to breath (no oxygen bottles). Question for the automn season, but answers for all seasons accepted too.

[image: Ishigaki airport to city by foot or bicycle, map]

Comment: What do you define as snorkelling spots? Essentially you could snorkel anywhere, it all depends on what you want to see. This link; http://www.ishigaki-japan.com/activities/snorkeling seems to suggest you can snorkel wherever you please.

Comment: @TheWanderingCoder: My question defines snorkeling spots as having fish and reef, ideally both, the more the better :-) For the North Coast there are [maps of outward currents](http://beach.yaeyamahazardmap.com/yonehara-rule/) (indicating places to avoid absolutely) but I haven't found such a map for the South-East. Most diving companies seem to congregate around Shiraho (白保).

Comment: from your image alone, it appears the island is surrounded by reefs (and presumably fish). The image you link to in the above comment seems to be a hand-drawn advisory for tidal movements at Yaeyama Beach. The snorkelling tour companies are mostly focussed just the West of your image however, there appear to be about 3 in this image (after a google search). Looking at most of their sites seems to imply that a good deal of the time the conduct tours off-island however there does not appear to be explicit notice that tours are conducted on "snorkelling spots" from the beach

Answer (score 2):

You could contact the local dive shops, and ask them, they would at least tell you where they take you when you take a trip with them.

Tom Sawyer +81 980-83-4677. http://www.ishigaki-tomsawyer.jp/

Hanalee Adventure Tours  +81 9031986472. http://hanalee-ishigaki.com/

Umicoza +81 980-88-2434. http://umicoza.com/en/